# update collection based upon other collection field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have 2 schemas, this is parent collection schema:

```
const TimesheetSchema = Schema({
    managersComment: {
        type: String,
    },
    weekNum: {
        type: Number,
    },
    year: {
        type: Number,
    },
    user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: userModel },
    status: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Saved", "Submitted", "Approved", "Rejected"],
    },
    data: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: TimesheetIndividualData }]
});
```

This is child collection schema

```
const TimesheetDataSchema = new Schema(
    {
        workingDate: {
            type: Date,
        },
        dayVal: {
            type: Number,
        },
        user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: userModel },
        parentId: { type: String },
        status: { type: String }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);
```

I want to update all `status` field in `TimesheetDataSchema(child collection)` based upon the `parentId`, here `parentId` is basically the `_id` of `TimesheetSchema (parent collection)`.

Not sure how to do that through query in mongoose/mongo,  so i am trying to do that through code in express.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

How about `db.timeSheetData.updateMany({"parent_id": ObjectId(_id)})` ?

(Edit)

- Fetch data from `TimeSheetSchema` collection.
- Iterate through it and for each `data` get the `_id`.
- `db.timeSheetsData.updateMany({"parent_id": _id}, {"$set": {"status": data.status}`

Comment: HI, I want to take status field value from `TimesheetSchema ` and update that value in `TimesheetDataSchema ` collection base upon condition `TimesheetSchema ._id === TimesheetDataSchema .parentId`